# Repairing a 1983 V65 magna Instrument panel

Tags: repair

The Regulator/Rectifier died and overcharged my battery and killed the a few components on this board. The component in the second image is kind of unrecognizable and I'm not sure what Z is on the PCB. I just need some advice on how to repair this. I feel like I should replace a few of the resistors and capacitors but any advice is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, I'm quite sure this is ***NOT*** what you're wanting to hear, but both of those PCBs are 100% ***FRIED***. The char marks & molten plastic tell me that at *least* 90% of the components on those boards have far exceeded all thermal tolerances. You're going to have to simply replace the whole thing.

Best case scenario: It looks like you might be able to salvage a few of the resistors & maybe the 2 switching diodes I see (but all of them together would cost less than $1 to purchase new...all the expensive parts are destroyed).

--EDIT--

Make that 4 diodes (the glass ones, the plastic one is dead).
Also, as a note, "Z" looks like what *used to be* a voltage regulator IC...now it's just the component that self-destructed in the most ostentatious fashion though.

Comment: Also, even if you could repair the brown PCB, you'd just end up with a green PCB that **very** likely also was damaged (but you can't see that damage easily). The amount of overvoltage to lead to this catastrophic failure simply has a high chance of damaging things that directly or indirectly attached to the failed components.

Comment: Yeah I don't want to hear that but it is what it is. The board actually still works believe it or not but some limited functionality. A replacement is not viable at this time... they don't make them and used are very expensive(even for damaged ones). Any idea what Z means on a PCB?

Comment: as Robherc said, probably a horribly failed voltage regulator that took a lot of other components with it. You'll really need to redesign that board from scratch, I wouldn't trust it if you just replaced a few components.

Comment: wow so someone just posted the Exact part on  ebay for super cheap!! 30$ for the whole unit... I greatly appreciate your feedback though!